# rails nginx passenger returning http 301 on linode VPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

i have deployed a rails app to linode VPS using capistrano. Now when i try to access http://mysite.com I get a 301 redirect to https://mysite.com, which fails because I don't have ssl setup

nginx conf file
`server {`
`listen 80;`
`server_name mysite.com;`
`root /home/stream_production/current/public;`
`passenger_enabled on;`
`rails_env production;`
`}`

access log
 - - [20/Oct/2012:14:29:23 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4"

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, rvm 1.15.8, ruby 1.9.3, rails 3.2.8, Phusion Passenger 3.0.17, Passenger's Nginx module.

Comment: SOLVED: this was caused by the following entry in my production.rb       file 

config.force_ssl = true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this was caused by the following entry in my production.rb file config.force_ssl = true
changing it to false solved the issue.